# Power Query - Merge Pivot Combined Columns into rows

Tags: powerquery

Hi, I'm creating a new thread since the problem I'm trying to solve is different to similar solutions which I've tried unsuccessfully.

I have a table with the following structure (see below), column "City" provides a list of cities A,B...D Column "Date 1" provides dates for the 1st date of an event happening at each city. Column "Date 2" provides the dates for the second event at each city.

| City | Date 1 | Date 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4/4 | 5/3 |
| B | 4/5 | 5/4 |
| C | 4/6 |  |
| D | 4/7 | 5/5 |

I'm trying to bring all the dates for both events into a single column as shown in the example below: Column "Date". While I'm able to pivot columns into rows using Power Query's Split function, I'm unable to solve this specific problem since the data across two separate columns "Date 1" and "Date 2".
Any Power Query ideas to solve this would be awesome, thanks in advance everyone!

| City | Date | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4/4 |  |
| B | 4/5 |  |
| C | 4/6 |  |
| D | 4/7 |  |
| A | 5/3 |  |
| B | 5/4 |  |
| D | 5/5 |  |

Answer (score 0):

Right click the City column choose "unpivot other columns"

Then remove extra columns, sort, rename columns as needed

Answer (score 0):

Another fairly quick way to do this in the GUI:

1. Select the date columns and click Merge Columns (under the Transform tab, Text Column section).
2. Choose a separator, say Semicolon, and click OK to do the merge.
3. Now choose Split Column > By Delimiter and choose the delimiter you just used (e.g. Semicolon).
4. IMPORTANT: Under advanced options, choose Split into **Rows** and click OK.
5. Filter out any nulls/blanks from the merged column.

---

@horseyride's suggestion is certainly fewer steps and cleaner code.

```
let
    Source = <Your Data Source Here>
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.Unpivot(Source, {"Date 1", "Date 2"}, "Column", "Date"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Columns", {"Column"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```